# Run promises in an array of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm having trouble running Promises in an array of arrays of objects.

I have a hardcoded example of some data

```
const page = [
    [
      {
        id: 1,
        text: 'sentence 1'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: 'sentence 2'
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        id: 3,
        text: 'sentence 3'
      }
    ]
  ]
```

A function called `getSentiment` takes a string and returns a `promise`

```
function getSentiment (sentence) {
  const rand = Math.random()
  if (rand < 0.3) { 
    return Promise.resolve(-1) 
  } else if (rand < 0.6) { 
    return Promise.resolve(0) 
  } else { 
    return Promise.resolve(1)
 }
}
```

Here is my code that maps this nested array that creates/adds a new key/property to the objects.

```
const resolvedPage = page
    .map(line => line
      .map(async sentence => {
        sentence.sentiment = await getSentiment(sentence.text)
        return sentence
      }))
```

`getSentiment` is called with async/await to get the value and assign to `sentiment` property and then return the object.

When I run `console.log(resolvedPage)` I get this

```
[
  [ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ],
  [ Promise { <pending> } ]
]
```

The result I expect should look like this:

```
[
[
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'sentence 1',
    sentiment: 0
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: 'sentence 2',
    sentiment: -1
  }
],
[
  {
    id: 3,
    text: 'sentence 3',
    sentiment: 1
  }
]
```

]

I tried using `Promise.all` but I'm not sure how to do it since my data is nested in an outer array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all` to wait for an array of promises to finish. With `flatMap` you can first map each line to an array of promises and then merge them together (flatten it), so it results in one big array of promises. So the updating is done inside the map. The return promises of the map calls are only used to wait for the promises to finish.

```js
const page = [
    [{ id: 1, text: 'sentence 1' },
     { id: 2, text: 'sentence 2' }
    ],
    [{ id: 3, text: 'sentence 3' }]
  ]

function getSentiment (sentence) {
  const rand = Math.random()
  if (rand < 0.3) { 
    return Promise.resolve(-1) 
  } else if (rand < 0.6) { 
    return Promise.resolve(0) 
  } else { 
    return Promise.resolve(1)
 }
}

const main = async () => {
  const promises = page
    .flatMap(line => line.map(async sentence => {
      sentence.sentiment = await getSentiment(sentence.text)
    }))
  await Promise.all(promises)
  console.log(page)
}
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap the async code in a function and use Promise.all
For example

```
(async () => {
  const resolvedPage = await Promise.all(
    page.map(
      async line => await Promise.all(
        line.map(
          async sentence => ({ ...sentence, sentiment: await getSentiment(sentence.text) })
        )
      )
    )
  );
  
  console.log(resolvedPage)
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something call for

```js
export async function myFunc (list) {
    for (const items of list) {
        
        for (const item of items){
             const result = await (your promise);
             //// rest of code
        }

   }

}
```

You might need to add the proper @babel/plugins to use it

Comment: It's 2021, we no longer need babel to use async/await :-)

Comment: Tell me that when your client opens your site on edge or IE

Comment: IE is a hopeless case, but Edge does support async await since a few years now (https://caniuse.com/async-functions)